# Android SDK Extras/ directory is missing

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm following the setup doc [here](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample) to get started implementing in-App purchase for Android.

The docs reference the `<sdk>/extras/google/play_billing/` directory and say to grab the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file from that directory and add it to your project.

Despite having downloaded the latest SDK and associated files using Android SDK Manager, the `Extras/` directory and this `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file are not present. Where can I find them?

(Frustrated side note: why are Google's Android docs so bad? Why do I need to copy a single file into my project instead of simply including a complete in-app-purchase jar?)

**Edit:**

[image: Per answers and comments below, the Google Play Billing Library appears to have been installed]

Comment: Are you 100% positive you have the Google Play Billing Library installed via SDK Manager? I just downloaded it and was able to locate the aidl file in that exact location.

Comment: See screenshot in the edited question...

Comment: I would make sure you don't have a duplicate SDK. Android Studio (if you're using it) comes with it's own Android SDK. If all else fails, I would probably uninstall that specific package and re-install it or a last resort of deleting the SDK and starting from scratch.

Comment: @AlexFu nice idea! This was the solution! I recently installed Android Studio after using IntelliJ for a while, and of course the SDK location has been changed. The extras directory is in the new location. If you post this suggestion as an answer instead of a comment I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure you don't have a duplicate SDK. Android Studio (if you're using it) comes with it's own Android SDK. If all else fails, I would probably uninstall that specific package and re-install it or a last resort of deleting the SDK and starting from scratch.

Comment: @Alex Fu May you elaborate a little on duplicate SDK?  I have an Android SDK downloaded for Eclipse.  Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You must download the **Google Play Billing Library** via the SDK Manager (in the Extras category). The SDK Manager will then create the `<sdk>/extras/google/play_billing/` directory, the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file, and sample projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, download **Google Play Billing library** using SDK manager.

[image: SDK manager]

Then go to

> **..\android-sdk\extras\google\market_billing**

. There you can find the file.